# how to save date for the second run of my application

Tags: php, date, crud

Here is what I did:

```
$time1 = date('h:i');
$time2 = null;
$time_array = array($time1, $time2);
```

$time1 is the current time. every time I run the script, it shows that moment.

I explain what I want to do:

```
at t=0 (initial) (first time I run the code)
```

`$time1 = 10:14:26;` (the date value that I want it to be saved for the use of the second run of the code)

Comment: Is your `$time2` supposed to be equal to your previous `$time1` ?

Comment: Yes, but it should be equal to $time1 when I run the code for the second time. So $time2 = $time1, and $time1 = (the time at that moment) when I run the code for the second time. @Hearner

Comment: save it in session or cookie

Comment: Or you asking how swap two variables?

Comment: I don't know how to use session or cookie but I can search for it if it is the way of doing what I want to do. No, not swapping 2 variables. Thanks @splash58

Comment: @Onur Good luck! It is not hard

Comment: @Onur , you want time like `10:14:26` shouldn't `date('h:i')` be `date('h:i:s')` ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to use session variables. But remember, if the user has cookies or private browsing enabled this will not work.

```
session_start();

if (isset($_SESSION['time_1'])) {
    $time2 = $_SESSION['time_1'];
}
$_SESSION['time_1'] = date('h:i');

$time_array = array($_SESSION['time_1'], $time2);
```